# Is it possible to save the state of a running Java process to disk and then resume it after some time?

Tags: java, process, operating-system, fork

Let's say I have a running Java application. Can I somehow write all the application's data to disk and then resume the process later on (start another process with the same data which will continue execution where the original process was stopped)?

Comment: There's nothing that would stop you from doing that.... writing the state to a database would be a more common solution

Comment: Which operating system do you use? Does it have to be two different processes, would "paging" the process entirely to disk and resuming *the same process* later work for you?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  There are many ways to serialize current state of the entire application or its relevant parts using Java serialization (binary), using JSON /XML/ Yaml/ Properties formats etc.

Comment: You might wanna explain what your main goal is. That could easily change the answers you're getting.

Comment: In general, this is imp....very difficult.  With app threads in various states, running, ready, waiting on I/O, inter-thread comms, syscalls inside the kernel, partial uncommitted out-of-process DB transactions etc etc, suspend/resume of an entire process is not something that can be guaranteed to work 100%.

Comment: @Joni I'd like to have an OS independent solution(if this cannot be achieved then I'd have different solutions for all platforms but in the end I'd still like to have a working solution for all the 3 major platforms: Windows, Mac OS, Linux).....

Comment: All modem operating systems use "virtual memory" and support paging, but the mechanisms to pause a process so that it can be paged are different